# Make a draw object option in Leaflet and that stores it in the webmap in a database or on a server

Tags: qgis, leaflet, polygon, web-mapping, web-service

I would like to set up a simple web map which should be used as an information for those out in the field that needs to show something immediately. So I would just load the web map and get an overview. 
The thing I would like to have is a map normal background map and then the user should be able to draw a polygon/point/line and that polygon should then be stored in a database or on the server.

For now I am going with Leaflet and QGIS.

Could someone tell me how it do this or provide links?

Comment: AFAIK, a "simple web map" like what you can produce with the `qgis2web` plugin is just for viewing data. Recording and uploading data is more complicated. Have a look at [qField](https://qfield.org/).

Comment: You probably need to look at WFS-T

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I will look it up and read more about it. QField is only for smartphone as I understod it?